# What is the verbal difference between 'dwelt in the bush' and 'dwelleth the cherubim'?

Tags: psalms, deuteronomy

The Hebrew verb occurring in Deuteronomy 33:16 :

> And for the precious things of the earth and fulness thereof, and for the good will of him that **dwelt** in the bush ... [KJV]

is *yoshev*.

The Hebrew verb occurring in Psalm 80:1 :

> Give ear, O Shepherd of Israel, thou that leadest Joseph like a flock; thou that **dwellest** the cherubims, shine forth ... [KJV]

is *shaken*.

I am interested if there is any significant difference in the meanings between *yoshev* and *shaken* which might have spiritual significance or if it is a marginal difference which does not warrant a spiritual significance being attached.

Is the difference between *yoshev* and *shaken* something like the difference between the English verbs 'occupy' and 'reside' ?

Comment: I know nothing of Hebrew, but I wondered if the meaning of 'shaken' in Psalm 80:1 could be 'enthroned'.  The NIV says "you who sit enthroned between the cherubim"; the NLT says "enthroned above the cherubim"; the ESV says "enthroned upon the cherubim".

Comment: In addition to the answer below, note that *yashav* is about 8x more frequent than *shakan* (1082 occurrences as tallied by Strong compared to 128). I'd say that *yashav* is a very general word, used not only for dwelling but even for simply sitting. For example, Moses "sat" (*yashav*) as a judge for the Israelites morning till evening in Ex. 18, till Jethro gave him the idea of appointing delegates. Cities can also *yashav* as in "be located". By contrast, *shakan* is almost always used of God, his name, his angels, his cloud (in Exodus), or a people group, in which case it means "settle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question; it was an interesting search.

While there were other places that discussed the different applications of these two words, I found the quote below to be the most interesting. I have not yet done a study to test the explanation, but am looking forward to doing so.

> **From Temple to Meeting House: The Phenomenology and Theology of Places of Worship** By Harold W. Turner Walter de Gruyter, May 2, 2011
>   - Religion - 418 pages
>
> http://tinyurl.com/y6dco3my  (Google Books - any typing errors are mine.)
>
> p. 93 - “…It is sufficient to note the similarity with Moses who goes
>   to the tent of meeting to speak with Yahweh in an intimate and
>   personal relationship, (e.g. Exodus 29:42-43) and the fact that the
>   tent was entirely mobile and free from all suggestions of the house of
>   God.
>
> Similar features of the tabernacle are stressed in the later
>   traditions about it. This is seen from a study of the usage of two
>   Hebrew verbs, *yashab* meaning to inhabit or dwell, and *shakan* to
>   sit down or ‘tent’ in a place. In the earlier writings when referring
>   to God little distinction seems intended between the two, and the
>   former is the commoner. With the Deuteronomic literature an important
>   distinction emerges, *yashab* being used for God’s dwelling in heaven
>   and *shakan* for his tabernacling on earth. The priestly writers go
>   one step further and never use *yashab* of God but always *shakan*,
>   placing the whole emphasis upon Yahweh’s tabernacling with men and
>   calling the Mosaic sanctuary *mishkan*, indeed the *mishkan* or one
>   tabernacle of the presence of God in this particular way.
>
> However much, therefore, the priestly writers were interested in the
>   Davidic tabernacle as authenticating their later temple they were even
>   more interested in the Mosaic tent of meeting as a solution to the
>   problem of the divine immanence and transcendence. God was the high
>   omnipotent Lord of the universe and yet had drawn near to Israel in
>   the desert covenant and remained with her through subsequent history.
>   How was such a God, who could not be regarded as dwelling in any
>   shrine, yet be present with his people? The answer lay in the
>   tabernacle, where Yahweh did not dwell (*yashab*), but where he
>   ‘settles impermanently’ (*shakan*) in order to meet with Moses in the
>   past, and in the same way, with his worshippers in the second temple.
>   ‘Priestly tradition has taken a concrete, archaic term, associated
>   with Israel’s desert tradition, and used it as an abstract term to
>   express a theological concept.’(7)...."